# How to handle dependent field validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

Hi have a use case where I have list of input fields with parameters as label names. I need to implement validation on inputted values and entered values on one field (eg. param 1)is dependent on the value in another parameter (eg, p4)
eg.

```
Param 1              <Input >
Param 2              <Input >
Param 3              <Input >
...
Param n              <Input >
```

error: Parameter 1 can not be greater than parameter 4.

I want to make the rules generic by giving validation rules with operators. What could be the best generic way to handle this use case.

I am using React in frontend

Answer (score 0):

for this implementation :
1 You will have to keep all the parameter into the state.
2 Check the value on onChange event.
3 in the function that is call on onChange event compare param1 state with param4 state if condition false then you can alert the user otherwise set the state.

Comment: i understand the implementation, i am looking for an option is there any way where i can define the rules and write generic code to handle that rules JSON

Comment: i am using React, i don't want to include another jQuery library for it any other npm module ?

Comment: are you using redux?

Comment: if use, then you can use redux form.